# How many variables got created in total inside a loop using `let`

Tags: clojure

I wrote the following function to print a value for 10 times:

```
(defn test-let []
  (loop [index 0]
    (when (< index 10)
      (let [x 2]
        (println "Value of x: " x))
      (recur (inc index)))))
```

My question is:

1. Did because of `let` inside the `loop`, 10 variables (representing the value 2) and only 1 symbol (`x`, that represent the variable that holds value `2`) got created?
2. If 10 variables were created, at what point they qualify for garbage collection?

Comment: Integers are primitives. There's no allocation involved.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are mixing up values and variables.  In your example above, there are 10 **values** created each time in the loop and are bound to `x` each time.  In Clojure, the local symbols (aka names) created by a `let` form are not variables (for example, like those top level symbols created by `def`).  Inside a `let` the symbols are just directly bound to the values.  See https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#let for more.  The Clojure compiler does *locals clearing*, and will generate code to remove references to local values once the locus of control leaves the local scope.  See https://clojure.org/reference/compilation#_locals_clearing for more details.  In your particular case of a value of `2` it probably does not mater since Clojure will use the primitive value directly.  I presume you were asking for the more general case where the value that is bound to `x` may be bigger than just a primitive.